# Стилизация, синхронизация select

Tags: javascript, jquery

1.Нужно стилизовать `select`, стрелочку я убрал, `background` линейный вертикальный задал, не могу стрелочку сделать... `select` вложенный в форму...

2.Нужно синхронизировать несколько `select` между собой, и так, есть 4-шт `select`, первый `select` обычный, остальные 3 `disabled`, при клике на первый `select` вторую `option` - второй `select` становится не `disabled`, все остальные кроме первого и второго `select` остаются `disabled`, при клике на первый `select` третью `option` - третий `select` становится не `disabled`, все остальные кроме первого и третьего `select` остаются `disabled`, так же с последним `select`...

```css
select {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 9px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%)
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <select class="select">
    <option selected class="region">Region</option>
    <option class="category">Category</option>
    <option disabled>ds</option>
    <option class="date">Date</option>
    <option class="prise">Price</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="catefory">
    <option selected>Category</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>3463</option>
    <option>64</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="date">
    <option selected>Date</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>46</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="prise">
    <option selected>Price</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>346</option>
    <option>3446</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Покажите код, которые у вас уже есть

Comment: html и сss? или только html?

Comment: @Ivan копируйте все коды сюда в виде текста

Comment: Примите правку, добавил сниппет в ваш вопрос.

Comment: большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код для синхронизации примерно такой:

```js
$("#main-select").change(function() {
  var activeSelect = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("class");
  $(".select:not(#main-select)").attr("disabled","disabled");
  $("#" + activeSelect).removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

```css
select {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-left: 9px;
  position: relative;
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #F4F3F1 0%, #fff 100%)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <select class="select" id="main-select">
    <option selected class="region">Region</option>
    <option class="category">Category</option>
    <option disabled>ds</option>
    <option class="date">Date</option>
    <option class="price">Price</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="category">
    <option selected>Category</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>3463</option>
    <option>64</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="date">
    <option selected>Date</option>
    <option>34</option>
    <option>43</option>
    <option>46</option>
  </select>
  <select class="select border-radius" disabled id="price">
    <option selected>Price</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>346</option>
    <option>3446</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: синхронизация все отлично спс) осталось, стрелочку сделать)

Comment: background:  url(../img/arrow.png) no-repeat 99%, url(../img/select-bg.jpg) repeat-x;

Comment: первая картинка самой стрелочки, вторая бекграунд всего селектора, нужной высотой и шириной 1пиксель что бы меньше места занимать))